# Make operations on different output lines

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

I made some script to arrange the output of a file and print the first field which is a time like this: `15:23:30`.

I tried to convert the first field by multiplying every section of it to convert it to seconds, then make a subtraction between every two lines, but I couldn't take every one line as argument to make the operation between every two lines.

```
for rec in $(cut -d " " -f2 file.txt | uniq -d); do
   grep -- "$rec" file.txt done |
awk '{split($0,a," "); print a[1] }'
```

the input file is like /var/log/messages

```
May 27 02:43:40 Rolly NetworkManager[2411]: <info> (eth0): DHCPv4 state changed renew -> renew
May 27 02:43:40 Rolly NetworkManager[2411]: <info>   address 192.168.159.133
May 27 02:43:40 Rolly NetworkManager[2411]: <info>   prefix 24 (255.255.255.0)
May 27 02:43:40 Rolly NetworkManager[2411]: <info>   gateway 192.168.159.2
May 27 02:43:40 Rolly NetworkManager[2411]: <info>   nameserver '192.168.159.2'
May 27 02:43:40 Rolly NetworkManager[2411]: <info>   domain name 'localdomain'
May 27 02:56:55 Rolly dhclient[2481]: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 192.168.159.254 port 67 (xid=0x3bb3abec)
May 27 02:56:55 Rolly dhclient[2481]: DHCPACK from 192.168.159.254 (xid=0x3bb3abec)
May 27 02:56:55 Rolly dhclient[2481]: bound to 192.168.159.133 -- renewal in 795 seconds.
May 27 02:56:55 Rolly NetworkManager[2411]: <info> (eth0): DHCPv4 state changed renew -> renew
```

and the desired output sould be the time column 
then make some operation on some lines of it

i want to get the output something like

```
1m 25s
```

and also if i can get the duration of some processes by subtract 2 values of the converted time

Comment: Can you add an example of input and the desired output? That would be really helpful.

Comment: *"Make some operation on some lines of it"?* I suppose you should write a script. If you don't tell us what operations you want to perform, we can't tell you how to do it.

Comment: i mentioned that above: convert the first field by multiplying every section of it to convert it to seconds, then make a subtraction between every two lines

Comment: [edit] your question to show the expected output given that input. See [ask].

Comment: i want to convert the time column to seconds to calculate the subtraction of some records of them but i couldn't

Comment: i modified it to show the expected output

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following `awk` script:

```
# initiate mapping array "Jan"->"01", "Feb"->"02", etc.
BEGIN {
    # assume all dates are from the current year
    YYYY = strftime("%Y", systime())

    # use first day of the month to extract month abbreviations
    # Note: Any day from "01" to "28" would work here.
    DD = "01"

    # use midnight as time for month abbreviation extraction
    # Note: Any (valid) time would work here.
    HH = "00"
    MM = HH
    SS = MM

    # assemble time string ("MM HH SS" format)
    timestr = MM " " HH " " SS

    # iterate over all months
    for (month = 1; month <= 12; ++month) {

        # convert month number to two-digit string ("MM" format)
        MM = sprintf("%02i", month)

        # assemble date string ("YYYY MM DD" format)
        datestr = YYYY " " MM " " DD

        # create timestamp (needs "YYYY MM DD HH MM SS" format)
        datetime = mktime(datestr " " timestr)

        # extract month abbreviation ("Jan", "Feb", etc.)
        monthstr = strftime("%b", datetime)

        # map month abbreviation to month string ("MM" format)
        monthstr2MM[monthstr] = MM
    }
}

# read timestamp from log input
{
    # convert month abbreviation in 1st field to string ("MM" format)
    MM = monthstr2MM[$1]

    # extract date from 2nd field (already in "DD" format)
    DD = $2

    # assemble date string ("YYYY MM DD" format)
    # Note: YYYY still is the current year for all timestamps. So this
    # will fail if the log spans the change from one year to the next.
    datestr = YYYY " " MM " " DD

    # extract time string from 2nd field ("HH:MM:SS" format)
    timestr=$3

    # convert time string to "HH MM SS" format
    gsub(":"," ",timestr)

    # create timestamp from "YYYY MM DD HH MM SS" format
    datetime = mktime(datestr " " timestr)
}

# if current timestamp differs from previous: print time difference
(NR != 1) && (datetime != previous) {

    # calculate time difference (in seconds)
    timediff = datetime - previous

    # print minutes and seconds passed since previous timestamp
    printf "%im %is\n",int(timediff/60),timediff%60
}

# store current timestamp for comparison with the next one
{
    previous = datetime
}
```

If now I save this as `timediff.awk` and your example input as `log.file` and run

```
awk -f timediff.awk < log.file
```

I get

```
13m 15s
```

which is exactly the difference between

> May 27 02:43:40

and

> May 27 02:56:55

Let me know if you need further explanations/adjustements.

Comment: thank you so much this is **perfect** script
, for me some functions are new like `mktime`
but the `previous` section i didn't get it

Comment: `awk` runs this code for every *record* (*i.e.* line) of the input. Thus, to compare the current line to the previous, we have to save the current timestamp in a variable (which will still be available when processing the next record). So I copy `datetime` to `previous` as `datetime` will be overwritten when processing the next *record*/line but `previous` will still have the 'old' value so i can compare the two. I could move this into the previous block to only update `previous` when needed, but then we'd need another block setting it for the 1st time (`NR==1`). I hope that clarifies a bit.